# How to use a GIF as a loading spinner in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

In the past, I've used successfully the `shinybusy` R package to add spinners to shiny apps, but this time I want to add a custom gif instead of the built in spinners

This example works, but the gif is just paused, rather than disappearing as it should when the server is not busy:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinybusy)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Use this function somewhere in UI
  # with navBarPage use the "header" argument
  add_busy_gif(
    src = "https://jeroen.github.io/images/banana.gif",
    height = "70px", width = "70px", position = "bottom-right"
  ),
  
  actionButton("sleep", "Long calculation")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$sleep, {
    Sys.sleep(5)
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I make the banana disappearwhen the server is not busy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add some custom css:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinybusy)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .ff-inactive {
        display: none !important;
      }"))
  ),
  add_busy_gif(
    src = "https://jeroen.github.io/images/banana.gif",
    height = "70px", width = "70px", position = "bottom-right"
  ),
  actionButton("sleep", "Long calculation")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sleep, {
    Sys.sleep(5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```